# Trying to insert an Avl tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, nodes, insert-update, avl-tree

I am trying to make an insertion method for an Avl tree but the structure and order of my nodes turns out to be incorrect. I am having trouble finding where i am going wrong.

Here are my methods
Any sort of help would be appreciated

template

```
void AvL<T>::insert(string val, T k)
{
    if (head == NULL) {
    head = new AvLNode<T>(val, k);
} else {
    put(head, val, k);
}
```

}

```
template <class T>
void AvL<T>::put(AvLNode<T>* root,string val,T key1) {
if (root->key > key1) {
    if (root->left != NULL) {
        put(root->left, val, key1);
        Balance(root, key1);
    } else {
        root->left = new AvLNode<T>(val, key1);
        root->bf = nodeHeight(root->left) - nodeHeight(root->right);
        root->left->parent = root;
    }
} else {
    if (root->right != NULL) {
        put(root->right, val, key1);
        Balance(root, key1);
    } else {
        root->right = new AvLNode<T>(val, key1);
        root->bf = nodeHeight(root->left) - nodeHeight(root->right);
        root->right->parent = root;
    }
}
}

template<class T>
void AvL<T>::Balance(AvLNode<T>* root, T key1)
{   root->bf = nodeHeight(root->left) - nodeHeight(root->right);
if (root->bf < -1 && key1 > root->right->key) {
    cout << "here1 ";
    LeftRotate(root);
} else if (root->bf > 1 && key1 < root->left->key) {
    cout << "here2 ";
    RightRotate(root);
} else if (root->bf < -1 && key1 < root->right->key) {
    RightRotate(root->right);
    cout << "here3 ";
    LeftRotate(root);
} else if (root->bf > 1 && key1 > root->left->key) {
    LeftRotate(root->left);
    cout << "here4 ";
    RightRotate(root);
}
}

template<class T>
void AvL<T>::RightRotate(AvLNode<T>* node)
{
AvLNode<T>* node1 = node->left;
node->left = node1->right;
node1->right = node;
node->bf = nodeHeight(node->left) - nodeHeight(node->right);
node1->bf = nodeHeight(node1->left) - nodeHeight(node1->right); 
node = node1;
 }

 template<class T>
 void AvL<T>::LeftRotate(AvLNode<T>* node)
{
AvLNode<T>* node1 = node->right;
node->right = node1->left;
node1->left = node;
node->bf = nodeHeight(node->left) - nodeHeight(node->right);
node1->bf = nodeHeight(node1->left) - nodeHeight(node1->right);
node = node1; 
}


template<class T>
int AvL<T>::nodeHeight( AvLNode<T> *n)
{
int lheight=0;
int rheight=0;
int h = 0;
if (n == NULL)
{
    return -1;
} else {
    lheight = nodeHeight(n->left);
    rheight = nodeHeight(n->right);
    h = 1+max(lheight,rheight);
    return h;
}
}
```

My .h file

```
template <class T> 
struct AvLNode
{
string value;
T key;
AvLNode *parent; // pointer to parent node
AvLNode *left; // pointer to left child
AvLNode *right; // pointer to right child
int bf; // Balance factor of node


AvLNode(string Val, T k)
{
    this->value = Val;
    this->key = k;
    this->parent = NULL;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
    bf = 0;
}
};
template <class T>
class AvL
{
AvLNode<T> *head;

public:
// Constructor
AvL();

// Destructor
~AvL();

// Insertion Function
void insert(string val, T k); // inserts the given key value pair into the tree
void Balance(AvLNode<T>* node, T key1);
void delete_node(T k); // deletes the node for the given key
void RightRotate(AvLNode<T>* node);
void LeftRotate(AvLNode<T>* node);
void put(AvLNode<T>* root,string val,T key1);
int nodeHeight(AvLNode<T> *n); // returns height of the subtree from given node
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your balance function is wrong. Since you've already inserted your new node into the tree, you don't need to worry about the key any more in `Balance()` - so the prototype should look like this:

`template<class T>
void AvL<T>::Balance(AvLNode<T>* root);`

The way you're doing it now seems to be attempting to balance based on the key you just inserted - which isn't necessary! You can balance the tree just based on the balance factors of nodes - here's how.

```
template<class T>
void AvL<T>::Balance(AvLNode<T>* root) {
    if (root->bf > 1) {
        if (root->left->bf == -1) LeftRotate(root->left);
        RightRotate(root);
    } else if (root->bf < -1) {
        if (root->right->bf == 1) RightRotate(root->right);
        LeftRotate(root);
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) - but you seem to have the idea almost down. The only thing you need to change conceptually is the idea that you're balancing based on the key you just inserted. You're not - you're balancing based on the shape of the tree, which you can get from just the balance factors of each subtree.

Comment: I inserted this function in my code to test but even after using this function the structure of my tree is still incorrect. I get where you are coming from in terms balancing by looking at the shape of the tree, because before i was using the key in my balance() i tried doing it with just the root but it wouldn't work therefore i resorted to using the key method.

Comment: could there possibly be an issue in my rightrotate or leftrotate function?

Comment: Ahhh I think so, actually. I'm not 100% sure - but in the last line of your `rotate()` functions, you do this: `node = node1;`. What you're trying to do is make `node1` the new root of your balanced tree - but that line doesn't work. All it does is reassign the value of the local variable `node` - it doesn't have any effect outside of the function. Try changing `void RightRotate(AvLNode<T>* node);` to `AVLNode<T> RightRotate(AvLNode<T>* node);`, and `node = node1;` to `return node1`, and all of your `rotateRight(root)` calls to `root = rotateRight(root)` - so you change the actual root node.

Comment: Even that doesn't fix the problem.I can't get where i am going wrong. When my program enters the balance function it never goes in any of the if conditions.